# Create New Array from Existing Array Values With Unique and Sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, chart.js

For some reason I'm stumbling to get the result I need with Javascript arrays.

I have rows of data which contain day, and several timestamps per row. What I need to do is transform that data to an array for chart.js, but merging rows by week, and summing the hours (from the timestamps). Below is where I am creating a new array from the query result, but am struggling to get it how I need it.

Here's where I create the array (with processing):

```
function chartData(queryrowlist){
  var weeks = [];
  angular.forEach(queryrowlist, function(value, key) 
  {
    weeks.push(moment(value.date).format('w'),getOnHours(value),getOffHours(value))
  });
  // create chart array ...
  return chart;
}
```

The weeks array ends up like this:

```
["23",28800000,3600000,"23",30300000,2700000,"24",35400000,3300000,"24",30000000,3300000]
```

Which is Week Number, OnHours, OffHours

The Week Number will be used as the Label, and the Hours as the On/Off Data in angular-chart/chart.js. The problem is all of the Week Numbers have to be Unique, and all of the Hours Summed up for each week.

So, I will need to output an array like this:

```
chart['weeks']=["23","24"]
chart['hours']=[[59100000,6300000],[65400000,6300000]]
```

This is probably simple, and it's just me hitting a thought wall... but if anyone has a solution, I'd be grateful.

Thank you in advance.

**Update:**

For anyone who might refer to this, the resulting array is incorrect for chart.js. Answers below are correct... as asked, I just asked the wrong thing and only realized after. Feeling like a fool :/

Chart.js want's all the line values in the same array, so instead of above example which is:

```
chart['weeks']=["23","24"]
chart['hours']=[[onhours,offhours],[onhours,offhours]]
```

It should be:

```
chart['weeks']=["23","24"]
chart['hours']=[[onhours,onhours],[offhours,offhours]]
```

**Update 2**

To add further clarification:

For each label, there should be a value. If you have 3 labels, you should have 3 values. In my case, there's 2 sets of value arrays, and that's because I have 2 series (2 lines), 1 for On Hours, 1 for Off Hours. So here's a complete list of arrays.

```
chart['labels']=["23","24","25"] // strings
chart['data']=[[onhours,onhours,onhours],[offhours,offhours,offhours]] // integers
chart['series']=['On Hours','Off Hours'] // strings
```

If I only needed 1 line:

```
chart['labels']=["23","24","25","26"] // strings
chart['data']=[[onhours,onhours,onhours,onhours]] // integers, notice [ [  ] ]
chart['series']=['On Hours'] // strings
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Could you expand on the example? e.g. if you have `chart['weeks'] = ["23", "24", "25"]`, should you also then have `chart['hours'] = [[onhours,onhours,onhours], [offhours,offhours,offhours]]`?

Comment: @HopefulLlama - Yes, that is correct. I've updated the examples. Hope that is more clear now.

Comment: I don't know if you needed, but I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not split into two arrays like you wanted?

```
function chartData(queryrowlist){
    // Set up our data store + return object
    var chart = {
        weeks: [],
        hours: []
    };
    // For every value in the parameter given
    angular.forEach(queryrowlist, function(value, key) {
        // Get the week, and check if it is in the array
        var week = moment(value.date).format('w');
        var weekIndex = chart.weeks.indexOf(week);

        // If the index is -1, it is not in the array, so just push values;
        if(weekIndex === -1) {
            chart.weeks.push(week);
            chart.hours.push([getOnHours(value),getOffHours(value)]);
        } else {

            // If the index is not, we assume that the weekIndex is the correct index to sum the values on.
            chart.hours[weekIndex] = [chart.hours[weekIndex][0] + getOnHours(value), chart.hours[weekIndex][1] + getOffHours(value)];
        }

    });
    return chart;
}
```

---

EDIT: New answer to reflect edit to question.

The algorithm will mostly stay the same, but the output array will change slightly.

```
function chartData(queryrowlist){
    // Set up our data store + return object
    var chart = {
        weeks: [],
        // Notice, two arrays in array
        hours: [
            [],
            []
        ]
    };
    // For every value in the parameter given
    angular.forEach(queryrowlist, function(value, key) {
        // Get the week, and check if it is in the array
        var week = moment(value.date).format('w');
        var weekIndex = chart.weeks.indexOf(week);

        // If the index is -1, it is not in the array, so just push values;
        if(weekIndex === -1) {
            chart.weeks.push(week);
            chart.hours[0].push(getOnHours(value));
            chart.hours[1].push(getOffHours(value));
        } else {

            // If the index is not, we assume that the weekIndex is the correct index to sum the values on.
            // Also notice the change to output to different arrays
            chart.hours[0][weekIndex] += getOnHours(value);
            chart.hours[1][weekIndex] += getOffHours(value);
        }

    });
    return chart;
}
```

Comment: They want to do a summing operation when the same week number occurs more than once.

Comment: @4castle Thanks, I don't know why I didn't notice that. Edited my answer to hopefully reflect it.

Comment: You can streamline that `else` block with `chart.hours[weekIndex][0] += getOnHours(value); chart.hours[weekIndex][1] += getOffHours(value);`. Also remember that `hours.push` should push an array, so `hours.push([getOnHours(value),getOffHours(value)]);`

Comment: This was right on... works great, is arrays, and it's commented. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for grouping and later sort the keys and build the chart object with the sums.

```js
var array = ["23", 28800000, 3600000, "23", 30300000, 2700000, "24", 35400000, 3300000, "24", 30000000, 3300000],
    chart = {},
    data = Object.create(null);

array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        if (!data[a]) {
            data[a] = { week: a, hours: [0, 0] };
        }
        return a;
    }
    data[r].hours[i % 3 - 1] += a;
    return r;
}, undefined);

Object.keys(data).sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
}).forEach(function (k) {
    chart.weeks = chart.weeks || [];
    chart.hours = chart.hours || [];
    chart.weeks.push(data[k].week)
    chart.hours.push(data[k].hours);
});

console.log(chart);
```

Comment: It might even be that a `reduce` would make more sense here, because it's ultimately doing a reduction operation in order to sum the values. It could make it easier to read.

Comment: would not work here, because i would lose `this.last`

Comment: Couldn't you give the reduction object a `last` field?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @chris, please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't need to maintain arrays for chart.js, I would use an object instead.

```
function chartData(queryrowlist){
  var weeks = {};
  angular.forEach(queryrowlist, function(value, key) 
  {
    var week = moment(value.date).format('w');
    if(!weeks[week]){ //new week
      weeks[week] = { 
        onHours: getOnHours(value),
        offHours: getOffHours(value)
      }
    } else { //week exists 
      weeks[week].onHours += getOnHours(value);
      weeks[week].offHours += getOffHours(value);    
    }
  });
  // create chart array ...
  return chart;
}
```

Result:
`weeks = { 23: { onHours: 59100000 , offHours: 6300000 }, 24: { onHours: 65400000, offHours: 6600000 }}`

And you would access it with `weeks.week#.onHours` or `weeks[week#]['onHours']`.

This will be much easier to read/follow/maintain than two separate arrays that need to be kept in sync.

Comment: They are exporting this to the chart.js API, so they can't modify the output format. My comment was misleading, so I've deleted it.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.